What are some highly unstable phenomena you can observe from lightyears away?
I'm currently drafting some scifi story where the protagonist is in a long timeloop and wants to figure out when the loop starts exactly based on observing some unstable phenomena, like atomic decay or neutrinos. The assumption being that the loop starts somewhere and the changes propagate roughly at the speed of light.
Observing things locally wouldn't be too hard - record something like a radioactive sample decay, note down some particularly notable patterns and their timestamps and see when such patterns change. But is there something you could try observing from another solar system to try noticing if the changes occured years back (due to distance plus speed of light limit).
My first thought was to try doing neutrino observations, but from what I understand it's hard to pinpoint where they came from exactly, plus probably local changes could affect if a particular neutrino gets detected or not.
So what would be some phenomena that could be observed from another solar system that could be affected by small perturbations in the initial conditions, aka something akin to "a butterfly effect"?

Why does it need to be highly unstable? How about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulse%E2%80%93Taylor_pulsar ?

how does a loop "start"? Isn't the entire point of a loop that it has no "beginning" or "end" points? also, if your observer continually revisits the same spacetime point, would there not at some point be a sharp observable discontinuity in the apparent motion of the stars?

@PM2Ring It needs to be highly unstable since the protagonist doesn't have good ways of affecting the phenomena from far away other than through stuff like light / lasers / EM waves. So their idea would be to see if there are other small changes to things like particle decay far away, or if they are the only source of change in the world (which is where I'm leaning towards currently).

@paulina The observer goes back to a point in their past except with their memories preserved. So it's like a Groundhog's Day, except it's decades long.

X-ray bursts, gamma-ray bursts, novas (accretion disk filling), supernovas (various types of stellar collapse), neutron star and black hole mergers would be examples.
